# output value with the same pattern

Tags: php, arrays, output

I have this code in php:

```
<?php
    $mails_list = "user1@example.com, User 2 <user2@example.com>, User 3 (user3@example.com)";
    $mails_arr = explode(',', $mails_list);
    foreach($mails_arr as $mail){
        echo "{$mail}<br>";
    }
?>
```

Note that with that code he output will be:

```
user1@example.com
User 2 <user2@example.com>
User 3 (user3@example.com)
```

And I dont want that. What I want is that the output must be:

```
user1@example.com
user2@example.com
user3@example.com
```

How can I do that with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) to capture all the emails with a regex:

```
preg_match_all('/[<(]?(\w+@\w+\.\w+)[>)]?/', $mails_list, $matches);
echo implode("\n", $matches[1]);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/219408)

Comment: @PSantos: Glad to have helped. Note that this will not work if the email addresses contain characters other than alphabets, numbers, and `_`. The fix is easy though, just change all occurrences of `\w+` to `[\w.+<more characters>]+` (replace `<more characters>` with whatever characters the email components are likely to contain).

Answer (score 2):

Here you go,

```
<?php
$mails_list = "user1@example.com, User 2 <user2@example.com>, User 3 (user3@example.com)";
$mails_arr = explode(',', $mails_list);

preg_match_all('/[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}/i', $mails_list, $found_mails);

foreach ($found_mails[0] as $each)  { echo $each.'<br>'; }
```